# Why does esky create 2 executables?

Tags: python, esky

esky 0.9.8 creates 2 executables of my application.
There is an inner executable that weights less then the outer executable.
I would like to know if esky is supposed to create 2 executables and if there are any drawbacks or advantages in creating 2 executables.
I would also like to know which executable should I be calling when I want to run my application.

Answer (score 1):

Esky uses a bootstrapping mechanism that keeps the app safe in the face of failed or partial updates.

The top level executable is the one you should be running, it does all the business of managing what version to run. Once it has decided what to run it will open up the exe for the correct version.

Comment: Thank you for your stream of answers. Could you help me with this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30965828/cant-uninstall-latest-version-in-esky?

Comment: can i suggest you to delete that new question? It's a continuation of your other post so we can discuss there http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29898272/cant-delete-old-versions-in-esky-0-9-8-python/30921780?noredirect=1#comment49961644_30921780